# maven build error when doing serverless deploy to aws ('dependencies.dependency.version' for com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:jar is missing)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, intellij-idea, aws-lambda

I have a serverless aws / java project (simple hello world type).

I can compile and build the application fine, but when I do a 'Deploy Serverless Application' on my template.yaml using IntelliJ IDE, I get a maven build error:

> ```
> Build Failed
> Error: JavaMavenWorkflow:MavenBuild - Maven Failed: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:jar is missing. @ line 46, column 21
> [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.amazonaws:aws-java- sdk:jar is missing. @ line 52, column 21
> ```

My pom.xml is as follows for those two dependencies. I also use DependencyManagement:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.651</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I could revert to using < version > tags again but then the rest of my application won't build due to the other dependencies I have. Also, I find using **aws-java-sdk-bom** a clean way of managing dependencies without needing to worry about versions and compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking on the pom.xml file of aws-jafa-sdk-bom on https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-bom/pom.xml

The dependencies "aws-lambda-java-events" and "aws-java-sdk" are not defined.

You should add the version number, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I haven't seen "aws-java-sdk" as a dependency anywhere.

Comment: But isn't the whole point of using the bom dependency management, not needing to specify versions? Or are you saying that bom doesn't support the "aws-lambda-java-events" and "aws-java-sdk" dependencies? Strangely, if I compile another Java program in my project, that relies on the same pom.xml for dependencies, I don't get any build error. It only happens when I do the 'Deploy Serverless Application' .

Comment: Yes, but BOM only defines a list of dependencies. So, it should be something related to the server less

Comment: Thank you - I specified versions for those dependencies not in the bom and this fixed my problem!